# How to sort a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have the following code which populates a DropDownList:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SPSite mySite = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb();
SPList list = myWeb.Lists["GuidelineTopics"];
DTable_List = list.Items.GetDataTable();
DTable_List.TableName = "Table1";
DTable_List.DefaultView.Sort = "Title ASC";
ds.Tables.Add(DTable_List);
Topic.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];
Topic.DataSource = DTable_List;
Topic.DataTextField = "Title";
Topic.DataValueField = "Title";
Topic.DataBind();
Topic.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Topics", "All Topics"));
Topic.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

How can I apply a SORT to the list so it is either ASC or DESC alphabetically?

Comment: Which list are you referring to? Look into Linq http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: `Topic` is my DropDownList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below. You can use the Linq [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) to get what you want.

If you want to sort your data source in ascending order of a column value then do

```
Topic.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"].OrderBy(x => x.Title);
```

Or if you want to sort by descending order on a particular column name then do

```
Topic.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"].OrderByDescending(x => x.Title);
```

Comment: Thank you. the `x` and `x.ColumnName` are pre defined?

Comment: That's your `fieldname` (Title) or any other column in the datasource that you want to sort on. May be I'll edit my answer with the actual field name.

Comment: Remember to add `using System.Linq;` to your code behind to take advantage of linq features.

Comment: thank you. I will test it oit and provide an updatr!

Comment: I added `using System.Linq;` but the `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` isn't coming up as an option.

Comment: I was looking at this article and maybe I have to use this: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2010/09/using-linq-to-order-sharepoint-list-items-and-choice-site-columns-within-a-dropdown-list/